# Sum count of unique value counts of all series in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am at my wit's end as I am writing this. This is probably an incredibly small issue, but I've not been able to get around it. Here's what is going on:

1. I have a dataframe `df` with `80` columns
2. Performing `value_counts().count()` over `df` iteratively, I am able to *print* the column names and the number of **unique** values in that column.

Here's the problem: What I am also wanting to do is `sum` up the `count()` of *unique* values of the all columns. Essentially I will need just one number. S0 basically, if column1 had 10 uniques, column2 had 5, column3 had 3.., I am expecting the `sum()` to be 18.

About #2, here's what works (simple for loop) -

```
def counting_unique_values_in_df(df):
    for evry_colm in df:
        print (evry_colm, "-", df[evry_colm].value_counts().count())
```

That works. It prints it in this format - `the column - unique values`

Now, alongside that, I'd like to print the sum of the unique values. Whatever I tried, it either prints the unique value of the last column (which is incidentally 2), or prints some thing random. I know it's something to do with the for loop, but I can't seem to figure out what.

I also know that in order to get what I want, which is essentially `sum(df[evry_colm].value_counts().count())`, I will need to convert `df[evry_colm].value_counts().count()` to a series, or even a dataframe, but I am stuck with that too!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [nunique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html), which returns a series across all your columns, which you can then sum:

```
df.nunique().sum()
```

---

My first instinct was to do it by series with a list comprehension

```
sum([df[col].nunique() for col in list(df)])
```

but this is slower and less Pandorable!

Comment: Worked. Like. A. Charm.